# NSDate throwing BAD_EXCESS for what?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, manual-retain-release

I have below.

```
@interface MyViewController () {
    NSDate *myCurrentDate;
}

@implementation MyViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myCurrentDate = [NSDate date];
}  


- (IBAction) prevAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"myCurrentDate===%@", myCurrentDate); // here it says 
    myCurrentDate = [myCurrentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*-1];
    [self formatDateAndPostOnButton];
}
```

When I try to print current date as below, it crash saying BAD_EXCESS

```
NSLog(@"myCurrentDate===%@", myCurrentDate);
```

Below is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

I'm not using ARC in my project.

***Any idea what is going wrong?***

Comment: Are these the only references to mCurrentDate? Or where else are you using it. In these lines of code I do not see any flaw.

Comment: Did you doublecheck by step-for-step-debugging that the exception is really trown on that very line.

Comment: @HermannKlecker : I have previous and next button... I update the variable `myCurrentDate` and then I update the label for display...

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski : nope... never...

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ problem found

Comment: what does it happen actually between `–viewdidLoad` and `–prevAction:` methods?

Comment: When you don't ARC then you should retain mCurrentDate. And don't forget to release it on -dealloc. `mCurrentDate = [[NSDate date] retain];`

Comment: Then better use ARC since you don't understand basics of memory management. That will help you building your application instead of fighting exceptions.

Comment: @trojanfoe : what is problem?

Comment: The variable is being released by the auto-release pool but the reference remains.

Comment: @trojanfoe : thanks... I got what was problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using ARC, easiest way to retain objects is to use generated setters/getters.

Instead of:

```
@interface MyViewController () {
    NSDate *myCurrentDate;
}
```

make

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate* myCurrentDate;
@end
```

So it will keep `NSDate` retained. Right now your `NSDate` gets deallocated when the auto-release pool is drained.

You will need to use the getters/setters provided, however:

```
self.myCurrentDate = [self.myCurrentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*-1];
```

Anyways I would recommend start using ARC to make your life simpler and avoid strange memory crashes.

Comment: You can't add property to interface variable block.